# Find combinations of 2 binary strings when the binary sum is given?

Tags: binary

Is it possible to find out the 2 binary strings when their sum is given?

Like if we sum the below 2 binary strings

```
01111001101001101101110111011011
01101010000010011110011001100111
```

we will get

```
11100011101100001100010001000010
```

but when this sum is given then can we find out the above 2 strings?

Comment: No it's not possible. Just like it's not possible to get the numbers used to compute the sum `4` (it could be `1 + 3`, it could be `2 + 2`, it could be `1 + 1 + 1 + 1`, and many other combinations).

Comment: or is there any way to find out all the combinations?

Comment: The most naive way would be to test all combinations of each number, from `00000000000000000000000000000000` to `11111111111111111111111111111111`. It's not complex, but isn't very efficient. A possible better way might be to use the knowledge that `0 + 0` is equal to `0`. `1 + 0` is equal to `1`, and that `1 + 1` is equal to `10`, and then find patterns in the sum to try and figure out possible combinations from that. For example the LSB in the sum is `0`, that means the LSB of the two numbers must be either `1` and `1`, or `0` and `0`. That way is not trivial to implement though.